# get data from selected slice of google charts PieChart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, pie-chart, getselection

i have big trouble trying to get the value of the selected slice of a PieChart when its clicked.

The documentation says:

> selection_array: An array of selected objects, each one describing a
>   data element in the underlying table used to create the visualization
>   (a DataView or a DataTable). Each object has properties row and/or
>   column, with the index of the row and/or column of the selected item
>   in the underlying DataTable. If the row property is null, then the
>   selection is a column; if the column property is null, then the
>   selection is a row; **if both are non-null, then it is a specific data**
>   **item. You can call the DataTable.getValue()** method to get the value of
>   the selected item. The retrieved array can be passed into
>   setSelection()

in my case i get null from getSelection(), then i couldnt figure out what to do to get the value i want (the label of the column corresponding to that slice).

Any answer will be very apreciated :)

the example code of what im doing:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['controls']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

var data;
var pie_area;

function drawVisualization() {
  // Prepare the data
  data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["rbd", "nombre", "area", "dependencia", "simceMat", "ubicacionLon", "ubicacionLat", "simceLen", "nivel"],
    [22616, "Colegio Mozart", "Urbana", "Part_Sub", 228, -72.981148, -41.479872, 254, "Basico"],
    [22686,"Escuela Basica Camelias","Urbana","Muni",228,-72.980075,-41.474599,253, "Medio"],
    [40351,"Colegio Bosquemar","Urbana","Part_Sub",290,-72.981148,-41.479872,280, "Medio"],
    [7633,"Escuela Capitan Arturo Prat Chacon","Urbana","Muni",317,-72.909565,-41.474567,314, "Basico"],
    [7659,"Escuela Rural Alerce","Rural","Muni",230,-72.91767,-41.399121,249, "Basico"],
    [7671,"Escuela Rural Lagunitas","Rural","Muni",261,-72.964282,-41.459485,269, "Medio"],
    [7690,"Escuela Rural Rio Blanco","Rural","Muni",217,-72.638597,-41.455786,229, "Medio"],
    [7700,"Colegio San Francisco Javier","Urbana","Part",305,-72.942089,-41.470351,303, "Basico"],
    [7717,"Instituto Aleman de Puerto Montt","Urbana","Part",321,-72.932482,-41.470001,310, "Medio"],
    [7718,"The American School","Urbana","Part",317,-72.909,-41.456,314, "Medio"]
  ]);

  var fltArea = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'f1',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnLabel': 'area',
      'ui': {
      'labelStacking': 'vertical',
        'allowTyping': false,
        'allowMultiple': false
      }
    }
  });

  pie_area = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      'chartType': 'PieChart',
      'containerId': 'chart2',
      'options': {
        'width': 300,
        'height': 300,
        'legend': 'none',
        'title': 'Area',
        'pieSliceText': 'label'
      },
      'view': {'columns': [2]}
    });

  new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).bind([fltArea], [pie_area]).draw(data);
  google.visualization.events.addListener(pie_area, 'select', onAreaSliceSelected);

}

function onAreaSliceSelected(){
  var sel = pie_area.getChart().getSelection(); //is always null
  console.log('you selected '+sel); //displays you selected null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in how your chart/data is set up.

You are currently aggregating all the data from column 2 to generate the chart. In this case you have 7 Urbana, and 3 Rural for your values, so it aggregates those 10 rows into two categories. Since each slice of the pie refers to a set of aggregate values, and pie charts only allow a single value to be selected, you can't get the selection of three rows that way.

Additionally, your category selector doesn't provide much use as it currently is, because if you select either Urbana or Rural, you end up getting a pie chart showing 100% of a single category.

If you set up your data differently, you will properly get an array of objects whenever you select a slice, as in this example:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Work', 11],
    ['Eat', 2],
    ['Commute', 2],
    ['Watch TV', 2],
    ['Sleep', 7]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  pieChart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
  pieChart.draw(data, {title:"So, how was your day?"});
  google.visualization.events.addListener(pieChart, 'select', onAreaSliceSelected);
}

function onAreaSliceSelected(){
  var sel = pieChart.getSelection(); //is always null
  alert('you selected '+sel); //displays you selected null
}
```

Comment: Ok jmac, i can see it now. but then, if i want to get a chart of that "area" column, should i build my own "mini" DataTable with the data i want to show, and update it when an event happen?

because i want to show 4 PieCharts that represents 4 categories, and offer the option to click slices from each chart to filter data of a very big table of data.

for example:
i got a big list of schools,

1 - click in "Urban" slice of the "Area Chart" filter out every school that is not in an urban Area.

2 - in the next chart select "Public", and filter out every school that is not public..

and so on.

Comment: I would suggest putting together the logic for how you want to allow users to sift through the data, and then figure out the best way to organize your data to do it. Unfortunately, it's not so easy to kind of "wing it" and then update as you go along, and generally planning things out beforehand to see how many tables/charts you need will save you many headaches in the long run.