# How to get selected slice from google pieChart

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using google pieChart with google API to display a pieChart on my website. I have coupled a select handler to the chart to display a DIV when a slice is selected. This works fine untill a user **clicks the same slice twice**, then the whole chart seems to crash.

I found out it was this piece of code that caused the crash

```
var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
var topping = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0); //this crashed the chart
```

I use the variable topping to get the slice name and to show the correct DIV... is there any other way to get the slide number/value/string to stop the chart from crashing?

Edit: I followed this tutorial and have a smilar chart on my website, they also use the same topping variable

[**Click here for the tutorial**](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_interactivity)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733690/get-data-from-selected-slice-of-google-charts-piechart

Comment: It looks like the tutorial checks `if (selectedItem)` and your code doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my own question, the lines of code in my post should be between the

```
if (selectedItem) { }
```

block.